# How to create separate instance for NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, nsmutablearray

In my application I need to create a copy of `NSMutableArray`. Currently I am using `mutableCopy` method. But when I modify the copied array the original one is also modified. Please tell me How to create a new copy `NSMutableArray`.
Here is the code

```
delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 self.mainImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[delegate.arrayForCarCaptureImages mutableCopy]];
```

and here i am modifying

```
UIImage *filteredImage =[[[[self.mainImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:valueVheck] objectAtIndex:j]  copy];
filteredImage =[filteredImage brightness:(1+sliderValue-0.5)];
[[[self.mainImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:valueVheck]removeObjectAtIndex:j];
[[[self.mainImagesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:valueVheck]insertObject:filteredImage atIndex:j];
```

After execution the arrayForCarCaptureImages also modified automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a deep copy. From what I understand, you're creating a copy of the NSMutableArray itself without making copies of it's individual elements.

From what I see in the code you've written:

> 1. You're abusing the delegation pattern
> 2. Your code is not readable. Try passing it along to another developer, I bet you'll get slapped very fast :)

Here's an example of a classic case of deep copying:

```
NSArray *numbersArr = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSMutableArray *numbersArrCopy = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSNumber *num in numbersArr) {
    [numbersArrCopy addObject:[num copy]];
}
```

An easier approach:

```
NSArray *numbersArr = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSArray *numbersArrCopy = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:numbersArr copyItems:YES];
```

This is of course different than just:

```
NSArray *numbersArr = @[@1,@2,@3];
NSArray *numbersArrCopy = [numbersArr copy];
```

Comment: 'self.mainImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[delegate.arrayForCarCaptureImages mutableCopy]];'  here Iam making copy of arrayForCarCaptureImages. and UIImage *filteredImage =[[[[self.mainImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:valueVheck] objectAtIndex:j]  copy];
                    filteredImage =[filteredImage brightness:(1+sliderValue-0.5)];
                    [[[self.mainImagesArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:valueVheck]removeObjectAtIndex:j];
                    [[[self.mainImagesArray objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:valueVheck]insertObject:filteredImage atIndex:j]; modify

Comment: Can you post an example for creating a deepCopy?

Comment: `- (id)initWithArray:(NSArray *)array copyItems:(BOOL)flag`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
NSArray *copiedArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[otherArray copy]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your project:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];

NSMutableArray *copiedArray = [array mutableCopy];


[array addObject:@"four"];
NSLog(@"copied %@", copiedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

MutableCopy will not perform deep copy. You have to do it manually as given,

```
NSMutableArray *arrayCopy = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id element in arraySource)
    [arrayCopy addObject:[element mutableCopy]]; //or [arrayCopy addObject:[element copy]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You code is hardly readable. See if this is working

```
delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.mainImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:delegate.mainImagesArray 
                                                  copyItems:YES];


UIImage *filteredImage = self.mainImagesArray[i][valueVheck][j];
filteredImage = [filteredImage brightness:(1+sliderValue-0.5)];
[self.mainImagesArray[i][valueVheck]replaceObjectAtIndex:j 
                                              withObject:filteredImage];
```